# Editing live Javascript with Chrome - Tab Crashes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've read you can edit javascript via Sources in Chrome so you don't have to refresh the page. But when i simply put in a console.log("test"); and then click the functionality that calls that function it crashes the tab. It provides not error or additional information

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is strange, I did this many times and it always worked. Could you give us more details, like chrome version, os ? Also, you could try opening a random page from the web and edit its javascript, maybe it's something related to the page you are trying to modify.

Comment: you should remove any `plugins` you have installed, hard for me to believe that chrome by its own crashes from editing a bit of js.

Comment: Appears i can edit other pages so there is something to do with this page. So i removed plugins but that didn't help. The site uses Angular which may be part of the problem. I'm on Windows 8 and Chrome 30.0

Comment: I've tried a windows 7 computer, same chrome version on the same site and it works. So it's something to do with Windows 8, chrome and something particular to this website. A combination that I'm afraid will be maddening to hunt down.

Comment: can't edit large js files in chrome. I am on windows 10. So much disappointed. Editing small js files is easy.